# Serving non-text files via http in C

Tags: c, http

I have a little web server in C which works fine when it has to serve html or css files. But when it comes to non-text files (image, compressed files, etc.), the data are corrupted when received by the client, which can't display them.

The response from the server is like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 11:24:27 GMT
Server: MacFly/0.1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Expires: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 11:25:27 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 06:13:38 GMT
ETag: "1041463782"
Content-Length: 36851
Content-Type: image/jpeg

���
```

The last line correspond to the corrupted data.
To generate the data, I use the following function which read the demanded file (any format : html, css, jpg, etc.) and save it in `file_contents` :

```
void get_content(const char * filename, char * file_contents) {
    FILE * file;
    int file_size;

    file_size = get_file_size(filename);

    if (file = fopen(filename, "rb")) {
        fread(file_contents, sizeof(char), file_size-1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the following line to allocate the memory :
`file_content = malloc(sizeof(char)*get_file_size(resource));`

Comment: Try using an `unsigned char*` buffer for your data rather than a `char*` buffer.

Comment: Why do you use `- 1` with `fread`? `get_file_size` return the size `+ 1`? I don't see other problems here and I think would be interesting to see how you write to the `stdout`

Comment: @Shan-x Is the buffer staying a `unsigned char*` all the way through, including the output to the socket?  Other than the `char*`, and the `-1` that @Alex mentioned, the read code looks ok.  (Remove the `-1` on the `fread`, you want to return the entire file.)

Comment: If you are on Linux (or BSD) you may also want to consider using `sendfile`

Comment: Does the size of the file received match the size of the file sent?

Comment: You should always check the return values of `fread` and `fclose`. How many objects did you *actually* read? Did any errors occur. Do you also output the result using a *binary* stream?